# Change a value in dataframe within loop without using 'loc'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

sol={'R4': -10.0, 'R5': 53.0, 'R7': -10.0, 'R1': 18.0,'R2': -3.0, 'R3': 19.0, 'R8': 6.0}

mat = pd.DataFrame(columns=sol.keys())
for i in range(5):
   s=pd.Series(sol)
   mat=mat.append(s,True)
mat.insert(len(next(mat.iterrows())[1]),'flag',0)

for idx, row in mat.iterrows():
    if idx>0:
        row.set_value('flag',1)

print mat
```

Output is:

```
   R4  R5  R7  R1  R2  R3  R8  flag  
0 -10  53 -10  18  -3  19   6    0  
1 -10  53 -10  18  -3  19   6    0  
2 -10  53 -10  18  -3  19   6    0  
3 -10  53 -10  18  -3  19   6    0  
4 -10  53 -10  18  -3  19   6    0
```

'loc' is not working. so I want a output like this (below) without using loc. The dataframe should update itself in a loop.

```
   R4  R5  R7  R1  R2  R3  R8  flag  
0 -10  53 -10  18  -3  19   6    0  
1 -10  53 -10  18  -3  19   6    1  
2 -10  53 -10  18  -3  19   6    1  
3 -10  53 -10  18  -3  19   6    1  
4 -10  53 -10  18  -3  19   6    1
```

Comment: Can you please format the output? It's hard to read right now.

Comment: And `mat['flag'] = 1` does not work?

Comment: Sorry I get confused: what is not working with your code right now? And you want to / have to use a loop?

Comment: The row of the dataframe will be modified (change of the value corresponding to 'flag') depending upon a condition. mat['flag']=1 modifies total column (flag) to 1. And in the actual code (this is dummy) I must use a loop.

Comment: Does the code you posted return an error? And if not, what is wrong with it?

Comment: no errors. but it returns the same dataset as previously (with all flag =0). But I want to modify a specific row where some condition satisfy.

Comment: Got it. I have a solution with `.loc` that works. Or do you want to avoid `loc` for some reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you specifically want to use a loop, this will work:

```
for idx, row in mat.iterrows():
    if idx > 0:
        mat.set_value(idx, 'flag', 1)
```

In your code, `row` was a copy, so modifying it did not change the original dataframe.

---

**EDIT**: updated to avoid `loc`. You should upgrade your pandas version though.

Comment: Ok. The 'loc' is not working thats why I need some other solution.      AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'loc'

Comment: And you can't upgrade pandas to a more recent version? You must be running 0.10 or below, you're missing on a lot of improvements!